# How to pass the data with AJAX to Controller in Laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am really stuck with AJAX request/response in Laravel and would be glad if someone could help me.

**This is my JS Ajax:**

```
$('#manufacturer_id').change(function(){
  var manuf_id = $(this).val();
  console.log("1:"+manuf_id);

  var dataString = '{manufacturer_id:'+ manuf_id+'}';
  console.log("2:"+dataString);

  // Ajax
  $.ajax({
    url: "/laravel/public/posts/create",
    type: 'GET',
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(dataString);
    },
  });
});
```

**And this is the PostsController, where I need to change just one ID:**

```
public function create(Request $manuf_id)
    {
        $title = 'Add post';

        $categories = Category::all();
        $manufacturers = Manufacturer::all();
        $fuels = Fuel::all();

        $sendedID = \Response::json($manuf_id);
        $cars = Car::where('manufacturer_id', $sendedID)->get();

        return view('posts.create',
            compact(
                'title',
                'categories',
                'fuels',
                'cars',
                'manufacturers'
            )
        );
    }
```

What I really want to achieve: When user select manufacturer from select box in my form, the ID of manufacturer will change the ID which is written here:

```
$cars = Car::where('manufacturer_id', $sendedID)->get();
```

Basically when I hardcode the number (ID) instead of variable $sendedID, I get everything I need (I already have releationships between the tables in my database).

All I need to do is to send the value (onchange) of manufacturer and pass it to variable $sendedID in my PostsController. I probably need to change the code in my PostController, just don't know how and I've already researched a lot, but could not find the answer. Thank anybody who has an idea how to repair this.

Answer (score 1):

In your JS you're trying to make a JSON string to send through to the server. There is no need to do this as jQuery will convert everything for you, so just send a normal Javascript object with your required params.

This also means you can clean up your server code as you no longer need to try decode the data sent.

For your JS:

```
$('#manufacturer_id').change(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/laravel/public/posts/create",
    type: 'GET',
    data: { manufacturer_id: $(this).val() },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(dataString);
    },
  });
});
```

Then in your controller:

```
public function create(Request $manuf_id)
{
    $title = 'Add post';

    $categories = Category::all();
    $manufacturers = Manufacturer::all();
    $fuels = Fuel::all();

    $cars = Car::where('manufacturer_id', request('manufacturer_id'))->get();

    return view('posts.create',
        compact(
            'title',
            'categories',
            'fuels',
            'cars',
            'manufacturers'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work for me. When I use alert(data) in the success function now I get full HTML code of my current page, not just a string with an integer of manufacturer_id.

And the dropdown for car models doesn't change according to manufacturer_id.

Comment: Of course you'll get the full html because that's what your create method is returning.

Comment: Yes, but how to show that data on the page for a user? I am little bit confused here, because working with Ajax and Laravel together is still a new area for me.

Comment: You have to refresh the page, not with ajax, if you want to do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your question, this is what you need:

> There is a dropdown of all your `manufacturers`. When a user selects one, options for `cars` will also change.

If you want to achieve this through *ajax*, you have to create a separate method to return all `cars` of a specific `manufacturer`. Let's say

```
public function getCars(Request $request) {
    $cars = Car::where("manufacturer_id", $request->get("manufacturer_id"))->get();
    return response()->json($cars);
}
```

Then your *ajax* method should be able to retrieve this data

```
$('#manufacturer_id').change(function() { 
    $.ajax({ 
        url: GET_CARS_URL, 
        type: 'GET', 
        data: { manufacturer_id: $(this).val() },
        cache: false, 
        success: function(data) { 
           console.log(data); 
        }, 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I tried this, variable cars is undefined and I get an error when I try to loop through it. I still don't see the response in my view and I'm kinda not able to do it. :/

Comment: You can use `return response()->json(compact('cars'));`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to attach the X-CSRF-TOKEN to send data via AJAX Request. check before send ajax request data is coming to your javascript variable and then in the controller dd() the request for data is successfully sent by ajax.

check the route is ok for send data via post. you can check all registered route it with php artisan route:list code in console...

how to attach the X-CSRF-TOKEN in ajax body

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: '/laravel/public/posts/create',
    type: "post",
    data: 'id=' + id ,
    success: function (res) {
       //response
    }
});
```

then check in the controller for if data receive correctly. if its a request object you can access the id with $request->id

```
Public function create(Request $request){
    dd($request); // this will show data receive from request
    $id = $request->id // access request object id
}
```

Comment: Route list showed me, that the posts.create use GET method, which should be fine, because this page is used for a form. Sending of this form is realeated to posts.store, but I am still not able to receive the data from ajax to my view. It's the first time I am confused by such a similar task so long and still don't get it.

Comment: sorry for the late response. yes GET is used for display . you are using resource route ,aren't you ?. that's good. then your form action must be `'/laravel/public/posts/create'` not this but `'/laravel/public/posts/store'` . change the ajax url to that.  and the function is store not the create.  
'Public function store(Request $request){
    dd($request); // this will show data receive from request
    $id = $request->id // access request object id
}'